# Button border colors in non-IE6 browsers

Tags: html, css, button, border

I am updating an IE6-era website so that cosmetic differences in modern (IE8, Firefox 4 in this scenario) browsers are eliminated, or at least reduced.

We've ran into an issue with buttons, which are styled using `background-color: #EFEFEF;` and `border: 1px`. In IE6 this `border` setting neatly reduces the border on buttons.
[image: IE6 button with default border]

[image: IE6 button with 1px border]

However, in IE8 and Firefox 4 setting a CSS style of `border: 1px` completely *removes* the border.

[image]

I've tried using `border_SIDE_color` to set the color of the relevant sides of the button appropriately but this has no impact.

What approach should I use instead? This is a large legacy website, containing many buttons so I am looking for a CSS-only solution, if one exists. Forcing IE8 into compatibility mode is also not an option.

Comment: Did you try: `border:1px solid black;` ?

Comment: @Briedis: This will just give me an all-round solid black border, which isn't consistent with what I need

Comment: Well, set the borders' color as backgrounds'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `border-style: outset;`. Or use the shorthand version with the other styles you're already using:

```
.mybutton {
    border: outset #EFEFEF 1px;
}
```

Comment: That will set all of the borders to the same color, which is not what I need. However, I think that what I've been missing is `border-style: outset;`

Comment: @Richard Ev: Not sure what you mean by "this will set all the borders to the same color", as I specified `outset` in the answer, which as you say is what you were looking for. Note that as I said in the answer, `outset` can also be used in the shorthand `border` style.